# How to install packages from git

Tags: software-installation, package-management, git

I want to install the package from the following URL:

https://github.com/VegetableAvenger/ARPSpoofing.git

I have executed the command `git clone https://github.com/VegetableAvenger/ARPSpoofing.git`
and have changed to the directory using `cd` command.

**Please, how do I install it?**

Comment: This would seem to be a better question for the git project it's self but at the same time, it looks like the project is old and no longer active there. maybe check for other forks that may be more up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *compile* the source code you cloned, issue `make` in the project directory.  To "install", you would copy the resulting executable `ARP_Spoofing` to any directory in your `$PATH`; or just leave it where it is and execute it from that directory as `./ARP_Spoofing`.

Ideally you would read the C++ source prior to running the resultant executable.

Comment: i got **ARP_Spoofing Error**  when i tried `./ARP_Spoofing`

Comment: Because you didn't include any of the mandatory arguments.  See the one-line shell script in the repository for an example of how to use `ARP_Spoofing`.

Comment: you are right @user4556274 i didn't include the mandatory arguments. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you are cloning a git repository, then it is most likely that you are downloading source code, which you will need to compile before you can install and use it. For many packages, this will mean running the following commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

It is recommended to run the first two commands as an unprivileged user and the last one as the superuser (root).

There are also some useful guides on the web for compiling software, such as [this one](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/install-from-source/).

**However**, that package you link to looks very simple and it doesn't seem to follow those general instructions above. It looks like just running `./ARP_Spoofing` (possibly with one of the listed options) from the source or installation folder should work. There is also a simple makefile in there, so if you wanted to re-compile it, it looks like you can just run:

```
make clean
make
```

Comment: `./configure` gave the error **zsh: no such file or directory: ./configure** and `make install` gave the error **make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.**

Comment: If you re-read my answer, those are general instructions that work for most packages. However, I mentioned in the last paragraph that that particular package is too simple, and gave the instructions that should work for yours.

Comment: Sorry if that confused you. The package you have doesn't use the Autoconf/Automake system, which is why the general instructions don't work.